# Get maximum value from a range based on a criteria that is dynamic

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, vlookup

So I have this spreadsheet where I'd like to extract the maximum value (last date) from a table range, but based on a criteria from a specific column in the table range. Initially I thought a nested MAX function and within it a VLOOKUP but soon realized that this would not work.

[image]

So from the table above, I'd like to have the dates in column H automatically display the last (max) date from the table in columns A-C, but I'd like the Arabic (H2) date to ONLY extract the max date from the Arabic criteria in the table and so on for French and German. I need this to be dynamic, because the table shown here is only representative, but in reality I have a table that spans over 400 rows and includes about 14 languages -- so I need the newest (max) date to automatically be extracted by a dynamic formula and not have to put individual MAX functions for each language to extract the newest date.

Can someone help/advise on how I should go about this?

Comment: You should probably set the range with the Max formula with an Offset.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your provided data, in cell H2 and copied down:

```
=MAX(INDEX(($A$2:$A$26=G2)*$C$2:$C$26,))
```